# hadoop map reduce functionality

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I did not understand the basic functionality of a mapreducer, does mapreducer helps in putting a file into HDFS
or mapreducer is only helpful in analyzing something from a existed file in HDFS
I am very new to hadoop, can any one direct me in understanding this

Comment: Have you actually looked for map reduce/hadoop tutorials? What do you specifically want to do?

Comment: Encourage you to read through this https://developer.yahoo.com/hadoop/tutorial/index.html

Answer (score 1):

The MapReduce is a programming model that divide the algorithm into a Map and Reduce phase. I encourage you to watch this video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HFplUBeBhcM
Moreover, try to understand the wordcount example. This is the simplest program in Hadoop MapReduce, it is like the hello word program in the other languages.